# Is there a way to extract data from a map(varchar, varchar) column in SQL?

Tags: sql, presto

The data is stored as map(varchar, varchar) and looks like this:

```
Date           Info                                                  ID
2020-06-10     {"Price":"102.45", "Time":"09:31", "Symbol":"AAPL"}   10
2020-06-10     {"Price":"10.28", "Time":"12:31", "Symbol":"MSFT"}    10
2020-06-11     {"Price":"12.45", "Time":"09:48", "Symbol":"T"}       10
```

Is there a way to split up the info column and return a table where each entry has its own column?
Something like this:

```
Date          Price        Time       Symbol       ID
2020-06-10   102.45       09:31         AAPL       10
2020-06-10    10.28       12:31         MSFT       10
```

Note, there is the potential for the time column to not appear in every entry. For example, an entry can look like this:

```
Date           Info                                  ID
2020-06-10     {"Price":"10.28", "Symbol":"MSFT"}    10
```

In this case, I would like it to just fill it with a nan value

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [subscript operator (`[]`)](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/map.html#subscript-operator) or the [`element_at`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/map.html#map-functions) function to access the values in the map. The difference between the two is that `[]` will fail with an error if the key is missing from the map.

```sql
WITH data(dt, info, id) AS (VALUES
    (DATE '2020-06-10',  map_from_entries(ARRAY[('Price', '102.45'), ('Time', '09:31'), ('Symbol','AAPL')]), 10),
    (DATE '2020-06-10',  map_from_entries(ARRAY[('Price', '10.28'), ('Time', '12:31'), ('Symbol','MSFT')]), 10),
    (DATE '2020-06-11',  map_from_entries(ARRAY[('Price', '12.45'), ('Time', '09:48'), ('Symbol','T')]), 10),
    (DATE '2020-06-12',  map_from_entries(ARRAY[('Price', '20.99'), ('Symbol','X')]), 10))

SELECT 
   dt AS "date", 
   element_at(info, 'Price') AS price, 
   element_at(info, 'Time') AS time, 
   element_at(info, 'Symbol') AS symbol, 
   id
FROM data
```

```
    date    | price  | time  | symbol | id
------------+--------+-------+--------+----
 2020-06-10 | 102.45 | 09:31 | AAPL   | 10
 2020-06-10 | 10.28  | 12:31 | MSFT   | 10
 2020-06-11 | 12.45  | 09:48 | T      | 10
 2020-06-12 | 20.99  | NULL  | X      | 10
```

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

If that is really a string, you can use regular expressions:

```
select t.*,
       regexp_extract(info, '"Price":"([^"]*)"', 1) as price,
       regexp_extract(info, '"Symbol":"([^"]*)"', 1) as symbol,
       regexp_extract(info, '"Time":"([^"]*)"', 1) as time
from t;
```

Comment: when I run this I get the following error: Unexpected parameters (map(varchar,varchar), varchar(18), integer) for function regexp_extract. Expected: regexp_extract(varchar(x), JoniRegExp, bigint) , regexp_extract(varchar(x), JoniRegExp)

Comment: @RyanReid . . . This answers the question that you asked:  "but the data is stored as varchar ".  That errors suggests that something is not a string.

Comment: Upon looking into it further, it seems the column is of the type "map(varchar, varchar)". Edited the question to reflect this. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: . . is it possible to answer this